# Charging a saved card in stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I want to charge a saved card in stripe. But while charging the save card I also want user to enter the CVV, just as an additional check (kind of like what happens in amazon).

So far I've tried payment intent and payment method. So while creating the payment intent I'll pass the payment method id, which is in format of card_***. And I can see that the payment_intent.succeeded event on stripe dashboard and even in webhook. But in this flow I'm unable to ask the user for CVV information.

Is there anyway to achieve this through Stripe.

Here's some useful links that I found.

[payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods)

This is the link that I followed to achieve, it's just that I also want to ask for CVV before actual charging.
[stripe doc for charging saved card](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to recollect the CVC from your customer.  As you mentioned, you’ll reuse the existing Payment Method, but additionally you’ll include a `cardCvc` element on the page where your customer can provide the CVC for their card.  Then when you’re making the call to confirm the payment, you’ll pass that element into the `payment_method_options.card.cvc` parameter.

This is covered in more detail here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment-cards-only#web-recollect-cvc

Comment: yeah it seems like it worked, but still I'm unable to confirm it cause even though I'm using only 3 digits for a testing card that requires atleast 4 digits cvc (378282246310005)  payment intent is succeeding, but when I'm passing no value for cvc then I'm getting incomplete_cvc error. Is there anyway to test this ? It seems like it's working but want to confirm properly.

Comment: That test card is designed to emulate an American Express card, which can have either a 3 or 4 digit CVC.  This is why the payment intent will have succeeded even if you only provided 3 digits for the CVC.  

The fact that you get an error when omitting a CVC is encouraging that this is working as expected.  It's difficult to confirm beyond that as the CVCs are protected fields and intentionally hidden from view.